# Ubuntu - PulseAudio - reciever losing sync always

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, hdmi

Backstory:

> Okay, so I have a receiver, an Onkyo TX-SR605.  It's connected to my Ubuntu media machine with an HDMI cable from my motherboard a BIOSTAR Hi-Fi A85S3.  Every time the receiver's input format changes, it makes an audible pop.  Not a big deal most of the time, but on my Ubuntu install it's getting a bit insane.  Every time sound starts or stops it makes that pop.  Also, I lose the first half-second or so of the media, so it's making the media machine thing not work out so well.

What I have tried:

> I've tried commenting the the line in defaults.pa that reads "load-module module-suspend-on-idle", and that works to a point, but it still switches a bunch when changing between 5.1 48khz and stereo 44.1khz audio.  Most of the documentation for pulseaudio seems to be old and/or nonfunctional.

My Question:

> **How do I lock pulseaudio into sticking with 48kz, 5.1 sound?
>
>   No resyncing, no new formats, just stick with that one.**

If this isn't possible, is there something else I can do?  I never had any problems at all under Windows 7, but I really don't want to go back to it because of audio pops.

`EDIT: 2016-21-21`

for dirkt:

I found that my receiver can do 192Khz reliably, so I'm switching to that for sample rate.

/etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.StdOne {
    type plug
    slave {
            pcm "hw:0,3"
            format S32_LE
            channels 6
            rate 192000
    }  
}
```

/etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=StdOne
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-udev-detect
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-rescue-streams
```

It still pops and clicks like no other.  Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: What I'd try is to write an ALSA [slave definition](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html) which restricts to 48 kHz and 5.1, then use [module-alsa-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index4h3) to make it visible to PulseAudio (and somehow disable usage of the original hardware device, if necessary). No idea if this will work, though, and I can't test it on my hardware (I don't get the pops).